# C & makefile: using source file with other name

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I'm pretty new to C and makefiles and thus do not completely understand the inner workings. As an assignment for school, I was told to make a spell checker, implementing three different ways. We were given a set of template files to work with.

In the main file (`spell-checker.c`), I include `hash.h`. This file gives me a few function prototypes.

I now have a few source files -- lets call them `hash-glib.c` and `hash-chain.c`. The first file uses glib and thus needs to include that library (hence the pkg-config stuff). I can manage to compile and run `hash-glib.c` using the following makefile functions:

```
%.o: %.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $< -c -o $@

hash-glib.o: hash-glib.c
    gcc $< -c `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` $(CFLAGS)

libhash-glib.a: hash-glib.o
    ar rcs libhash-glib.a $<

spell-checker-glib: spell-checker.c libhash-glib.a
    gcc spell-checker.c  -L. \
        -lhash-glib `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` $(CFLAGS) -o $@
```

I tried adding the following to get my desired result (to no avail):

```
libhash-chaining.a: hash-chaining.o
    ar rcs libhash-chaining.a $<

spell-checker-chaining: spell-checker.c libhash-glib.a
    gcc spell-checker.c -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
```

What am I missing here? (and for future reference -- what are some keywords I might look into?)

Thanks alot!

EDIT: This is the output:

```
$ make spell-checker-glib
gcc hash-glib.c -c `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2
ar rcs libhash-glib.a hash-glib.o
gcc spell-checker.c  -L. \
            -lhash-glib `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2 -o spell-checker-glib
$ make spell-checker-chaining
gcc spell-checker.c -o spell-checker-chaining -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_hash_table_new", referenced from:
       _main in ccGPxFvR.o
  "_hash_table_insert", referenced from:
      _main in ccGPxFvR.o
 "_hash_table_fill", referenced from:
      _main in ccGPxFvR.o
 "_hash_table_size", referenced from:
      _main in ccGPxFvR.o
 "_hash_table_lookup", referenced from:
      _main in ccGPxFvR.o
 "_hash_table_destroy", referenced from:
      _main in ccGPxFvR.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [spell-checker-chaining] Error 1
```

Comment: Ok, this isn't really a makefile problem.  To solve this, I suggest figuring out the correct `gcc` incantations by hand (i.e. by typing them in at the command-line).  Once you have that solved, adapt the makefile as necessary.

Comment: After a bit of fiddling, I managed to solve the problem retracing my steps. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
spell-checker-chaining: spell-checker.c libhash-glib.a
    gcc spell-checker.c -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
```

This compiles `spell-checker.c` into `spell-checker-chaining`. It requires that `libhash-glib.a` exist, but doesn't use it, and doesn't mention `hash-chaining` at all, so the compiler has no idea what it's supposed to use for hash functions.

I suggest you try the following:

```
spell-checker.o: spell-checker.c
    # I'm kind of guessing here, I don't know what flags this object needs.
    gcc $<  `pkg-config --cflags` $(CFLAGS) -o $@

# I'm assuming spell-checker-chaining doesn't use glib.
spell-checker-chaining: spell-checker.o hash-chaining.o
    gcc $^ -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
```